# Scaling android app to screen

Tags: android, user-interface, scale

I have developed an android app, but I have encountered a problem:

when the screen height is to small, my app's UI is not comprised entirely by the screen.
And certain buttons are not visible because the layout does not fit the screen.

I am using a TableLayout and have set its properties to "match_parent".

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the entire `TableLayout` in a `ScrollView` so that the user can scroll up and down the table. Shrinking may result in hard to read text if you put too much on a small screen.

Comment: Make sure if you do this to change the height of the TableLayout to `wrap_content` (and the ScrollView should have it's height as `match_parent`)